# Optimize MySql Query - avg() with inner join taking more time

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Taking more time when averaging with inner join, if i want to query 100+ villages avg() it takes serious time:

```
select avg(audit_main.score)
from `audit_main`
inner join `farmer_details` on `audit_main`.`id` = `farmer_details`.`audit_main_id` 
inner join `farmers` on `farmer_details`.`farmer_id` = `farmers`.`user_id`  
inner join `address` on `farmers`.`address_id` = `address`.`id`  
where `audit_main`.`certification_id` = 4
     and `farmer_details`.`mill_id` = 22  
     and `farmer_details`.`administrative_division_id` = 166
     and `address`.`village_id` = 139543;
```

[image]

Comment: Share indexing details on the table (if any). Share the `EXPLAIN` statement results as well.

Comment: For table details show (as formatted {} text) `SHOW CREATE TABLE audit_main`, for each table, and `EXPLAIN SELECT .....`.

Comment: Do you want all averages for each village in one query, like `SELECT address.village_id, avg(audit_main.score) FROM ....`? Does the other `WHERE` critieria stay the same?

Comment: How many values do you think it is averaging?  Add `COUNT(*)` to the `SELECT` to see if you guessed right.  If the count is much bigger than expected, then it is not averaging what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL uses 1 index per table in a query.

To start the indexes, look at what elements are in the `WHERE` clause.

This means there should be an:

- `audit_main` that begins with `certification_id`;
- `farmer_details`
  that begins with `mill_id`, `administrative_division_id` (any order); and
- `address` that begins with `village_id`

Next look at what the tables they are joined to and it it isn't a primar key, append this:

- `audit_main` has `id`, which because its assumed to be a PK, doesn't need to be added.
- `farmer_details` has `farmer_id` (assumed to be PK)
- `address` has `id`, assumed to be PK,
- `farmer` has `address_id` and `user_id` (assumed PK)

Lastly look at the results set. In this case only `audit_main.score`, which since its a small length field can be appended.

So, assuming indexes don't exist already:

```
CREATE INDEX idxCertScore ON audit_main (certification_id,score);
CREATE INDEX idxMillAdminDiv ON farmer_details (mill_id, administrative_division_id);
CREATE INDEX idxAddress ON farmer ( address_id);
CREATE INDEX idxVillage ON address (village_id );
```

After adding these indexes, show `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` query to see if all these are used correctly.

References:

- [How MySQL uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)
- [Query Optimization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization)
- [Compound Indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1)

Comment: You're welcome. What was the resulting `EXPLAIN SELECT ....` output? If you want to query all villages that probably can be done quickly in SQL compared to individual queries. Responding to questions/comments will usually give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest these indexes:

```
audit_main: (certification_id, id)
farmer_details: (audit_main_id, farmer_id, mill_id, administrative_division_id)
farmer_details: (mill_id, administrative_division_id, audit_main_id, farmer_id)
farmers: (user_id, address_id)
farmers: (address_id, user_id)
address: (village_id, id)
```

This allows the Optimizer to start with different tables, possibly finding a better order to look at them.  Also, many are "covering", which gives another boost.

(It would help to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)